# Send Fluentd log to a opensearch installed in a different machine : Could not communicate to OpenSearch, resetting connection and trying again. [302]

Tags: fluentd, opensearch

I've been trying to send the Fluentd log to a opensearch, those two are installed in two different machines.
fluentd.conf match clause is the following :

```
<match **>
 @type copy
 <store>
  @type forward
  @id forward_output
  <server>
   name TisaOS
   host private_ip
   port 24224
  </server>
  <buffer tag>
   flush_interval 1s
  </buffer>
  <secondary>
   @type opensearch
   host public_ip
   port 5601
   ssl_verify false
   user admin
   password admin
   index_name fluentd
  </secondary>
 </store>
 <store>
  @type stdout
 </store>
</match>
```

I access to opensearch in the browser with private_ip:port

I've been trying for a while, some help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you communicate with opensearch machine from the one which sends log on port 24224?

Comment: @Riz Yes, I can. I already sent the logs from fluentd to another fluentd but I'm trying to minimize the process and send them directly to OpenSearch.

Comment: You haven't provided anything by the way. Do you get errors? Make fluentd emit debug logs and see what issues do you get. Also have you installed opensearch plugin? or elasticsearch(works for opensearch as well)?

Comment: @Riz Yes I did install the fluent-plugin-opensearch, and for the error I got : Could not communicate to OpenSearch, resetting connection and trying again. [302] Since the script sends logs directly to OpenSearch I'm not sure if I have to use a configuration file in the log aggregator machine as well.

Comment: add `scheme https/http` to your config and use only ip and not http/https etc or use http or https without `scheme https/http`.